# Websockets in Kestrel and .NET core 6

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, asp.net-core-6.0, kestrel-http-server

In the code below I am accepting incoming WebSocket connections. I have added the webSocket option:

```
WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync(new WebSocketAcceptContext
{
    DangerousEnableCompression = true
});
```

I try to ensure each message sent compressed like this:

```
 var messageType = WebSocketMessageType.Binary;
 var compressMessage = true;
 await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(messageBytesToSend), messageType, GetMessageFlags(true, compressMessage), CancellationToken.None);
```

My question is: When receiving a message, is any way for me to determine if an incoming message was sent compressed or not compressed over the wire (e.g. from a browser)?

Here's the full code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseWebSockets();

app.Map("/ws", appBuilder => appBuilder.UseMiddleware<WebSocketMiddleware>());

app.Run();

await app.RunAsync();

public class WebSocketMiddleware
{
    private static Timer _timer = null;
    private static ConcurrentBag<WebSocket> _connectedSockets = new ConcurrentBag<WebSocket>();

    public WebSocketMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
        if (_timer == null)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(SendMessage, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
    }

    public async void SendMessage(object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sending message...");

        string s = new string('A', 2048);

        byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello: " + s);

        foreach (WebSocket webSocket in _connectedSockets)
        {
            if (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                await SendMessage(webSocket, messageBytes);
            }
        }
    }


    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private ConcurrentBag<Task> _socketTasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync(new WebSocketAcceptContext
            {
                DangerousEnableCompression = true
            });

            _connectedSockets.Add(webSocket);

            Console.WriteLine("WebSocket connection established.");

            var socketTask = ReceiveMessages(webSocket);
            _socketTasks.Add(socketTask);
            await socketTask;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
            await _next(context);
        }
    }

    private async Task ReceiveMessages(WebSocket webSocket)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
        WebSocketReceiveResult result;

        do
        {
            result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

            byte[] messageBytes = new byte[result.Count];
            Array.Copy(buffer, messageBytes, result.Count);
            OnMessage(webSocket, messageBytes);

        } while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue);

        await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    protected virtual async Task OnMessage(WebSocket webSocket, byte[] message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message)}");
    }

    protected virtual async Task SendMessage(WebSocket webSocket, byte[] messageBytesToSend)
    {
        var messageType = WebSocketMessageType.Binary;
        var compressMessage = true;

        await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(messageBytesToSend), messageType, GetMessageFlags(true, compressMessage), CancellationToken.None);
    }

    private static WebSocketMessageFlags GetMessageFlags(bool endOfMessage, bool compressMessage)
    {
        WebSocketMessageFlags flags = WebSocketMessageFlags.None;

        if (endOfMessage)
        {
            flags |= WebSocketMessageFlags.EndOfMessage;
        }

        if (!compressMessage)
        {
            flags |= WebSocketMessageFlags.DisableCompression;
        }

        return flags;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could check your byte data if that contains compressed byte usually zipped data contains 8 in 3rd byte or you even can check header content type.